# Will Loader destroy automatically

Tags: android

I have seen loader is not destroying automatically when activity is destroyed. Is it so when activity is destroyed loader keeps on working doinbackground till it not completes its task. I have also seen it sets listener to null when activity is destroyed so don't give callback. But read that loader destroys automatically on activity destroy. How it works?

Comment: [This](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) series of tutorials will help you.

Comment: No this is not helping